# How can I move folders which contain certain letters in a directory through CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to move all folders (and contents) within MyDocuments which contain the phrase "hello" to C:\test

I thought the syntax would be: `Move *hello* C:\test` in Win7

Can't seem to find anything online - *mondays am I right?*

Thank you in advance,

Comment: That will move anything with hello in the file / directory name to c:\test but it will only check the local directory, not any subdirectories. And it will only check the filename, not the contents. Can you clarify exactly what you're after

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I want all folders and subsequent files in that folder to move to `C:\test` which contrain hello in the folder name. Thanks